# Why do I have different connectionstrings when releasing?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, connection-string, localdb

I'm a little confused on this one - I have made a desktop app that works fine on my dev machine(s), but, I just can't seem to deploy it.

I'm having fun and games with the EF connection strings/config.

I made a method that appears really early in my app. All it does is call:

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString.ToString());
```

Debug:
[image]

Release:
[image]

I have blurred out sensitive parts, but, I don't get why it is different on Dev to release. Does anyone know?

And, how can I fix - I have tried numerous connection strings, but, it just doesn't seem to change anything?

All I have done is added this, along with no other connection string in app.config:

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration {
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
        SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());

        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new LocalDbConnectionFactory("MSSQLLocalDB"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps there is an app.config, or section, for debug and one for release. This is the case with web.configs anyway.

Comment: @Mackan - only the one app.config which has no transforms or anything else :(